Nuclear physics theoretical doubt
Half life for certain radioactive element is 5 min. Four nuclei of that element are observed at a certain instant of time. After half life i.e. 5 minutes, half of total nuclei will disintegrate. So only two nuclei will be left undecayed.
Why is this incorrect?

Nuclear disintegration is a probabilistic process, you cannot say for sure how many nuclei will disintegrate after a certain amount of time

I have 4 fair coins, so when they're tossed they have a probability of 0.5 of showing heads. If I toss all 4 coins, will exactly 2 of them show heads?

This question is similar to: The number of active nuclei left after a half life has passed. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/699733/174766

Nuclear decay is a quantum process which, as eveything in quantum mechanics, means it is a probabilistic process. When you talk about the half life of a radioactive element, you are actually talking about the time in which there is a 50% chance of a single individual decay to have happened. If your sample is really big, you will have a number of decays at this time which is close to this 50% average. However, to a small number of nuclei in the sample, statistical fluctuations are large and deviations from this average can be huge. For example, If you had a sample with $2\times10^8$ components, the number of those who decayed at the moment that you reach the half life time would be close enough to half to ignore the fluctuations (e.g. $1\times10^8 - 4 \approx (2\times10^8)/2$). However, with only four nuclei, you could easily arrive at the same time with no decays, a single decay, etc.
You are incorrect just in the sense of lacking the statistical interpretation of the process, understanding it as completely deterministic.
